# Joint probability integral

Tags: probability, integration

Why is it that:

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{X,Y} (u,v) \, dv$

is a function of u?

Comment: They're just dummy variables. You may replace them again with $x$ or $y$ after integrating.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey I understand that but do you mind showing that this is a function of u in a step by step manner?

Answer (score 0):

This is a function of $u$ and $y$ because different values of $u$ and $y$ correspond to (possibly) different values of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this is joint distribution where support of y is y<=0, if this is so this will give you the marginal distribution of fx(u) thus a function of u.